# Oracle FlexCube Universal Banking - FLEXCUBE UBS Data Model – DDL scripts location

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get Oracle FLEXCUBE UBS Data Model. I am reading the following Oracle documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E94300_01/PDF/Extensibility/FCUBS-FD08-01-01-Data%20Model%20getting%20started.pdf

[Oracle documentation to get FlexCube Data Modell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMpjx.png)

I can't find path location on server. Does anyone know DDL scripts location on Oracle Server?
Any hint how to search ?

FCUBS_12.2.0.0.0\MAIN\DATABASE\HOST\CONSOL\DDL\TABLE

FCUBS_12.2.0.0.0\MAIN\DATABASE\BRANCH\CONSOL\DDL\TABLE

FCUBS_12.2.0.0.0\MAIN\DATABASE\EL\CONSOL\DDL\TABLE

FlexCube version is 12.0.3.6.2

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the path for the DDL scripts,

You can find it in this path:

FCUBS_12.2.0.0.0\MAIN\DATABASE\HOST\CONSOL\DDL\TABLE

This is for versions before 14.

From 14 Flexcube has split to multiple products and UBS Core DDLS can be found in below path:

FCUBS_14.4.0.0\ROFC\MAIN\DATABASE\HOST\CONSOL\DDL\TABLE